# How to delete a file using Cordova?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

*Note: this question is being re-posted because for whatever reason the original poster decided to remove it after an answer was provided and accepted. I am therefore adding it again to preserve the knowledge*

---

**Original question:**

I'm trying to understand how the crud operations for cordova appache works.
I created a delete function in worklight as follows:

index.html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="deleteAudio();">Delete the local MP3 file</a><br/>
```

main.js:

```
function deleteAudio() {
  var entry= "file:///data/data/com.TestApp/files/4638.mp3";
  function success(entry) {
    alert("Removal succeeded");
 }

  function fail(error) {
    alert('Error removing file: ' + error.code);
 }

// remove the file
entry.remove(success, fail);
}
```

when trying to delete, it is not deleting the code. i'm getting this error:

```
10-11 09:54:14.419: E/NONE(1821): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught TypeError: Object file:///data/data/com.TestApp/files/4638.mp3 has no method 'remove' at (compiled_code):68
```

Can i have any help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot simply have a variable that contains a path to a file and use the `.remove` method on it. For all intents and purposes it's just a variable with some string inside it. That's basically what the error is saying. It does not know what `.remove` is.

`.remove` will be available only after you have gained access to the filesystem.
The following works:

```
var entry= "file:///data/data/com.TestApp/files/4638.mp3";

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL (entry, 
    function (fileEntry) { 
        fileEntry.remove(
            function () { 
                alert('File is removed.'); 
            }, 
            function (error) {
                alert('Unable to remove file.');
            }
        ); 
    } 
);
```

Since this continues [the previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326618/how-to-handle-files-using-cordova/33326619#33326619), here is the full example:

**index.html**

```
<button id="downloadMP3">Download MP3 file</button><br/>
<button id="playMP3" disabled>Play MP3 file</button><br/>
<button id="stopMP3" disabled>Stop MP3 file</button><br/>           
<button id="deleteMP3" disabled>Delete MP3 file</button>
```

**main.js**

```
var mediaFile;
var mediaPlayback;

function wlCommonInit(){
    $("#downloadMP3").click(downloadMP3);
    $("#playMP3").click(playMP3);
    $("#stopMP3").click(stopMP3);    
    $("#deleteMP3").click(deleteMP3);
}

function downloadMP3() {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var remoteFilePath = encodeURI("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4638.mp3");
    var localDownloadPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + '4638.mp3';

    alert ("Downloading...");
    fileTransfer.download(
        remoteFilePath,
        localDownloadPath,
        function(successResponse) {
            mediaFile = successResponse.toURL();
            // Remove "file://" so file could be found and later played.
            mediaFile = mediaFile.replace('file://','');
            $('#playMP3').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#stopMP3').prop('disabled', false);            
            $('#deleteMP3').prop('disabled', false);
        },
        function(errorResponse) {
            alert (JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
        }
    );
}

function playMP3() {
    mediaPlayback = new Media(
            mediaFile,
            function() {
                alert("Finished playing audio file.");
            },
            function() {
                alert("Failed playing audio file.");
            }
        );

    mediaPlayback.play();
}

function stopMP3() {
    mediaPlayback.stop();
}

function deleteMP3() {
    // Put back "file://" since it is needed in order to be found.
    mediaFile = "file://" + mediaFile;

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(mediaFile, 
        function (fileEntry) { 
            fileEntry.remove(
                function () { 
                alert('File is removed.'); 
            }, 
            function (error) {
                alert('Unable to remove file.');
            }); 
        } 
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am looking for this function too.